# How do you represent a linear combination of an array of values?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $A$ be an array of values. I want to transform it into a new array $B$ by the rule
$$B_{m,n} = A_{m-1, n-1} + mA_{m, n-1} + nA_{m, n}.$$

If $A$ had been a vector, I would represent this by a matrix $T$ and write $B = TA$, but how do I do this for an array?

I tried to represent the transformation in matrix form but the first term is giving me trouble, since it's on a different row and column. Matrix multiplication from the left allows me to combine column elements and from the right row elements, but I can't seem to get anything else to interact.

Comment: I thought about "flattening" $A$ into a vector, but that feels pretty clunky especially given that $A$ is infinite in both dimensions.

Comment: where does the indices of the matrix live? You can consider their bivariate generating functions.

Comment: To write a general linear relation between matrices you would need a 4th order tensor. It may not be possible to write this relation as a simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: I would pack the $A_{mn}$ into a sequence of polynomials by $A_n(x)=\sum_m x^mA_{mn}$ and write something like $B_n(x)=nA_n(x)+x(A_{n-1}(x)+A'_{n-1}(x))$.

Comment: @Daniel Cunha I thought about that, but didn't want to mention tensors since I don't really understand them. Thanks for confirming my suspicion!

Comment: @Phicar  and kimchi lover I'll look into generating functions, thanks!